# SQL How to count multiple columns with similar values

Tags: sql-server, count, multiple-columns

I have a table with item sales for several stores, see sample table below.

```
  Store   Item   Price   Cost   Profit  
 ------- ------ ------- ------ -------- 
  ABC     Beer       5      3        2  
  ABC     Beer       5      3        2  
  ABC     Beer       4      3        1
```

I need to count items with similar prices, so result for above table should be similar to...

```
  Store   Item   Count   Price   Cost   Profit  
 ------- ------ ------- ------- ------ -------- 
  ABC     Beer       2       5      3        2  
  ABC     Beer       1       4      3        1
```

I tried following SQL query with no success...

```
SELECT Store,Item,Count(Price),Price,Cost,Profit
FROM Table
GROUP BY Store,Item,Price,Cost,Profit
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Your query is correct and is returning your expected result. What does it give you?

Comment: I get 3 rows with count of 1 for each row

Comment: The query is correct. There must be some hidden character in your varchar columns because I have just now tested it in on my own system and produces the correct output.

Comment: Are you not actually trying to get a "count" of rows whose column values are similar?

Comment: Are any of those numbers you are grouping by a float? If they are, you will need to cast them as a decimal with an appropriate precision and scale to get this to work.

Comment: @neualex see the explanation below and give us some feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that *I need to count items with similar prices*. Given your sample data, your query works.

```
declare @table table (Store varchar(3), Item varchar(16), Price int, Cost int, Profit int)
insert into @table (Store, Item, Price, Cost, Profit) 
values

('ABC','Beer',5,3,2),
('ABC','Beer',5,3,2),  
('ABC','Beer',4,3,1)  

SELECT 
    Store,
    Item,
    Count(Price) as CT,
    Price,
    Cost,
    Profit
FROM @table
GROUP BY Store,Item,Price,Cost,Profit
```

**However**, if the `Cost` and `Profit` columns for each `Store / Item / Count` `tuple` is different, your grouping wouldn't show the results you want.

```
declare @table2 table (Store varchar(3), Item varchar(16), Price int, Cost int, Profit int)
insert into @table2 (Store, Item, Price, Cost, Profit) 
values

('ABC','Beer',5,3,2), --notice change in cost and profit
('ABC','Beer',5,2,1), --notice change in cost and profit 
('ABC','Beer',4,3,1)  

SELECT 
    Store,
    Item,
    Count(Price) as CT,
    Price,
    Cost,
    Profit
FROM @table2
GROUP BY Store,Item,Price,Cost,Profit
```

I **assume** in your real data, this is the case--that is your `Cost` and `Profit` are different. Thus, you need to remove those columns from the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` in order to answer your question, *I need to count items with similar prices*. **Additionaly**, you may want to remove the `Store` column from the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` as well.

```
SELECT 
    Store,
    Item,
    Count(Price) as CT,
    Price
FROM @table2
GROUP BY Store,Item,Price
```

Comment: Price may change, usually markdown or original price, cost never changes. I guess I have to make use 2 tables to get the results I need. First table, store/item/count/price, second table to include cost/profit.

Comment: @neualex  normalizing your data as you are suggesting is usually a great idea

Comment: If I only have one store on the table such as ABC, the count on similar prices is correct for that only store, but if I had at least 3 different stores (S1, S2, S3) and they all have similar prices, how can I count similar prices per store? Same query counts similar prices for all stores, not per store. I can provide data if needed.

Comment: @neualex the last query does it per store. Removing store from the select and group by will give you the overall results. If this doesn't work I would open a NEW question and provide sample data and expected output so everyone can help out